# Problem to index with django-python using django_elasticsearch_dsl

Tags: django, elasticsearch-dsl, oai-pmh

I'm working on a project using **django-python**. This has "**oaisearch**" installed to retrieve the metadata from different websites and "**django_elasticsearch_dsl**" to index them. It was verified that "oaisearch" runs without problems.
The problem occurs when "`python3 manage.py search_index --create -f`" is run to start indexing.
The file "**documents.py**" that has the configuration of what you want to index is the following.

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer

from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index

from oaisearch.models import Digital_Resources

digital_resources = Index('digital_resources')

digital_resources.settings(
    number_of_shards=1,
    number_of_replicas=0
)

html_strip = analyzer(
    'html_strip',
    tokenizer="standard",
    filter=["standard", "lowercase", "stop", "snowball"],
    char_filter=["html_strip"]
)

@digital_resources.doc_type

class Resources(DocType):
    class Meta:
        model = Digital_Resources
        fields = [
            #'oai_server',
            'creator',
            'title',
            'subject',
            'description',
            'identifier',
        ]
```

The console failure message after executing the aforementioned command is as follows

```
Creating index 'digital_resources'
PUT http://localhost:9200/digital_resources [status:400 request:0.014s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 128, in handle
    self._create(models, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 84, in _create
    index.create()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/index.py", line 203, in create
    self.connection.indices.create(index=self._name, body=self.to_dict(), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 88, in create
    params=params, body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 318, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 186, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [doc : {properties={identifier={type=text}, creator={type=text}, subject={type=text}, description={type=text}, title={type=text}}}]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of elasticsearch are you running? It looks like you are running elasticsearch 7.x which is not yet supported by your version of `django_elasticsearch_dsl`. Try looking for a newer version or using elasticsearch 6.x.

Comment: Thank you. I was using version 7.0.0 of elasticsearch, then I used version 7.0.1 of elasticsearch and it did not work either, then I tried version 6.5.1 and it worked perfectly